# htaccess simple redirect without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect people who go to my site but I want it to not show in the URL.

http://www.example.com/  ->  http://www.example.com/dev/

except the /dev part shows in the URL when the redirection takes place, how do I hide it so it stays as http://www.example.com/? Here's my HTAccess file..

```
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    dev/index.php    [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What URL are you going to that is causing the redirect? Because it's not your mod_rewrite rules

Comment: @user1157885: Is `/dev/` a real directory?